# Prevent require.js from caching text files?

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory, requirejs

I'm loading a rather large text file using the require.js text plugin. It is required by a module that parses it as JSON and uses the data to hydrate some models. After that, the original text is no longer needed.

As far as I know require.js keeps everything it has loaded in memory. Is there a way to prevent that?

Another option would be to load the text file manually via AJAX but doing it via require.js would be much more convenient.

I do NOT want cache busting solutions. The file is only loaded one time and I just don't want to keep it in memory when I no longer need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the requirejs doocumentation you can "undef" a module:
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef

This won't free memory for pieces of your code that have already required the module, but for those you could unset the local version via my_module = undefined.